# Send HTML string to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I want to send a HTML string data to nodejs server, but when the API method just doesn't pick up the data string. It was working fine when I send over the pure text string without html tags. Do I need to encode the html string before sending to server?

```
HTML data string looks like this: <p> Some text </p>

Pure data string looks like this: Some text
```

Thank you.

Client side code:failed.

```
 pushData(value: any) {
  return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3030/api/postdata/' + 'This is a test', {observe: 'body'}).subscribe(res => {

  }, err => {
   
  });
  }
```

Client side code:passed

```
 pushData(value: any) {
  return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3030/api/postdata/' + 'This is a test', {observe: 'body'}).subscribe(res => {

  }, err => {
   
  });
  }
```

Server side code:

```
app.post('api/postdata/:data',function(req,res){
const stringData = req.data;
}
```

Comment: You will have to show the exact code you're using to send the string to the node.js server so we can see what the code is actually doing.  Questions about code should include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I have updated with the client and server side codes.

Comment: I don't know what type of client you're using, but data submitted with a post does not go in the URL, it goes in the body.  Also, in Express, `:data` would show up as `req.params.data`, not `req.data`.  And, you can't put spaces in the URL, you will have to encode it properly if you're going to have spaces and `app.post('api/postdata/:data'` should be `app.post('/api/postdata/:data'` with a leading slash.

Comment: @jfriend00.  I am using Angular 4 type scripts. I think the body and the req.data are not the issue. Because it is working with the string. If I pass in the string with HTML tags then the data not going through. You got the point maybe the HTML tags string needs to be encoded. Are you referring the URL Encoding? Please advice.

Comment: Yes, URL encoding.  Why are you using POST if you're not sending any actual data in the body?  I promise you `req.data` won't hold `:data`.  It's `req.params.data` unless this isn't the Express framework.

Comment: @jfriend00. You got the point. I will re-look into the code again. Thank you for the advice about the encoding.